# do i need to register a company to use Stripe or Paypal in production (i live in canada)?

Tags: javascript, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

When using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) or [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/) to accept credit card payments in production, do I need to register a company?

(Edit: I know I can test it in sandbox mode, I'm talking about REAL payment)

Comment: You can get a PayPal Merchant Account. So you do need to register, but you can operate in the sandbox, so your account is not affected.

Comment: Stripe lets you process live payments as an individual. To process live payments, you simply need to create a Stripe account, log into your dashboard, click on the "Test" toggle to switch it to "Live" and fill the form with the required identity verification information. Once the account is activated, you can start processing live payments immediately.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER #1: [IANAL](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/IANAL) and this is not legal or financial advice.**

**DISCLAIMER #2: This does not address the legality of doing business in Canadian Law, only in the rules of the payment processors.**

No, you do not need to register a company to accept credit card payments using either of those providers. Both of them will accept your personal information (identity and bank account) to make payments to you.

However, that means that it is your responsibility to handle all applicable taxes in your personal tax filing. **Additionally, any liability that arises as a result of any transactions you do will apply to you personally.**  The primary benefit that you get from creating a company is that it shields your personal finances from the company's finances and can possibly protect you from suffering direct personal financial harm. It also helps you if you ever want to transfer the account to someone else.